How to force 0 intercept in linear regression analysis in xmgrace?
I have a data set (x and y) and want to determine the slope of the line with a high R-squared value. To find the equation of the line, I performed a linear regression analysis in xmgrace, which resulted in an equation that includes an intercept. However, I would like to set the intercept to zero, but I'm unsure how to do that.
Can anyone guide me on how to set the intercept to zero in xmgrace and obtain the line equation in the form y=mx?
